# PHP MVC Call Model in another Model

Tags: php, model-view-controller, methods, model

Sorry if the question has already been asked, but I have wanted to know if import a model in another model MVC is correct or whether it is best to do the same function in EVERY models?

For now in the Model in my Library folder I add the same method as in my Controller:

```
class Model
{
    protected function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database;
    }

    public function model($model)
    {
        require_once '../app/models/' . $model . '.php';
        return new $model();
    }
}
```

And in my model file :

```
class Exemple_model extends Model
{
    function __construct ()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function exemple_function()
    {
        $otherModel = $this->model('urlAnotherModelFile');
        $otherModel->otherMethod();
    }
}
```

But I am not sure it is correct to do so or if is the best way.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with import? extend?

Comment: oh I see, wait let me write an answer.

Comment: model is a layer, not a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are kind of mixing things up I think.

Your controller is responsible for creating models, and executing methods on them. You can rename you `Model` class to `BaseModel`, and make each model extend from this `BaseModel`.

As for the problem of including the right files, I would recommend you take a  look at the autoloader: http://php.net/manual/de/function.spl-autoload-register.php. This may look a bit confusing at first, but if look at the first example you will quickly understand what is the gist of it: basically if you want to create a object of a specific class, php checks if it already knows that class, and if not, it will execute the autoloader (which then tries to include the file containing the class). As soon as you have configured the autoloader, you can stop caring about including the right files.

As autoloader might be a bit confusing at first, this would be the autoloader in your specific use case:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($model) {
    include '../app/models/' . $model. '.php';
});
```

You need to put this snippet somewhere before you construct / access a model. Everything else is done by php (it calls automatically the function as it needs to, so calling something like `spl_autoload_register('Comments_model::comments_list');` would not work at all :)

Now if you want to execute a method from a model, you can do this as following:

```
$otherModel = new otherModel();
$otherModel->otherMethod();
```

no worries about `require` or similar, php does this for you.

Comment: I agree to the Controller, but the problem is that, I've a Model for news and another for comments, but I need to retrieve the Comments Method directly in the News Model so I was looking for a way to do without having to retype the same Method twice in every model.

Thank you for autoload, I'll look at it more closely.

Comment: Oooh I think understanding : spl_autoload_register();

If I want use Comments Method in my New Model I need to do :
spl_autoload_register('Comments_model::comments_list');

For example, right ?

Comment: @Djihell You might want to consider moving the method out of your model into the constructor then. I think the safest way to programm nicely if every part of your programm has one and just one purpose. Models have the purpose of holding Data, and sometimes formatting them, for example a Date. Any other logic, as accessing a database or similar, should be moved to the controller.

Comment: Okay, thanks you for your help, I try this and I come back to say whether this is good or not !